# Get active cms pages assign and not assign to the Store

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, store-view

How to get all active cms pages and then if they doesn't exist in the Store show near N/A

```
$pages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
```

Comment: what you means by  "store show near N/A?"

Comment: I mean it's should be in result something like this

cms_page | store_name | available(or exist)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
$collection->setFirstStoreFlag(true);
$collection->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
```

**setFirstStoreFlag()** `set flag $this->_previewFlag=true` for add  `Store table (cms_page_store)` to collection  cms page using `_afterLoad()` function on class `Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page_Collection`.

Then using function `addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getstore())` filter the collection.Also note that you need store id not website is:

**`$collection->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore())`**

Comment: I just check this. Not exactly what I want. As result it's should be all active page with field store, and if page not exist in store show N/A on return in query null result. 

It's should by join by two tables cms_page and core_store as I understand.

Comment: yes, actually i amnot understard your quesion for first before put comment .Now  understand the question.Will update answer soon.